# On the interpretation of Fredholm's second theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Throughout this post $T\colon X\to X$ is a compact operator and $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space. Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely Fredholm Theory of compact operators. In the text, the author gives the following propositions:

> **Proposition 1**:
>
> - $(i)$ $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)^\perp=\text{ker}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$, and because $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)$ is a closed subspace, if $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)\neq X$ then $\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\neq\{0\}$.
> - (ii) $\text{ker}(T-\lambda I)=\text{Im}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)_\perp$ and moreover,
>   $$
>   \text{ker}(T-\lambda I)^\perp=\text{Im}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I).
>   $$

> **Proposition 2**: $\text{ker}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\neq0$ if and only if $\text{ker}(T-\lambda I)\neq0$

The author then gives the following paragraph:

> **Paragraph A**: An interpretation of Proposition 1 and 2 is *Fredholm's second theorem* which answers the question: " when does the equation
> $$
> Tx-{\lambda}x=y\tag{1}
> $$
> have a solution $x\in X$ when $\lambda\neq0$ and $y\in X$ are given?" To answer this, consider the homogeneous part of the dual (adjoint) equation in $X^*$:
> $$
> T^*f-{\overline{\lambda}}f=0.\tag{2}
> $$
> Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_k\}$ be the maximal set of linear independent solutions (we know that it may be at most finite). Then, a solution $x$ of $(1)$ exists if and only if $f_i(y)=0$, $i=1,\dots,k$. This is proposition 1.

This paragraph is where I have some questions. Firstly, why do we know that $\{f_1,\dots,f_k\}$ may be at most finite? Secondly, how does $(1)$ imply a solution $x$ of $(1)$ exists if and only if $f_i(y)=0$, $i=1,\dots,k$?

I'm lost with the first question, but for the second question here is my attempt. For the second question, it's enough to show that $f$ being a solution of $(2)$ implies a solution $x$ of $(1)$ exists if and only if $f(y)=0$. It's clear that $f$ being a solution of $(2)$ means that $f\in\text{ker}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$. By proposition 1, $f\in\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)^\perp$. Writing this set out,
$$
\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)^\perp=
\{(T-\lambda I)x:x\in X\}^\perp=
\{f\in X^*:f((T-\lambda I)x)=0\,,x\in X\}.
$$
Thus $f((T-\lambda I)x)=0$. Hence if $x$ is a solution then $(T-\lambda I)x=y$, so $f(y)=f((T-\lambda I)x)=0$, i.e. $f(y)=0$. However, I'm not sure how to show here that if $f$ is a solution and $f(y)=0$, then $x$ is a solution to $(1)$...

Comment: What do you mean by $\perp$ in a Banach space?

Comment: @SatwataHans It's the annihilator, i.e., $A^\perp=\{f\in X^\ast: f(a)=0\text{ for all }a\in A\}$.

Comment: Finiteness of $\{f_1,...,f_k\}$ is clear from the fact that Ker$(T^*-\bar{\lambda})$ is finite dimensional if $T^*$ is compact and $\lambda\neq0$. This is because, let $Z=$Ker$(T^*-\bar{\lambda})$. Then $T^*(Z)\subset Z$ and $T^*|_Z$ is also compact. Furthermore, $T^*|_Z\equiv \bar{\lambda}\mathbb{1}_Z$, hence the $\mathbb{1}_Z$ map is compact which is possible iff $Z$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @SatwataHans: Thanks for clearing that part up! Any idea about the second question?